# Organizing Python Libraries and Folders

Tags: python, organization

I'm having a lot of issues managing my python folders and directories. 
I installed python normally, had my happy "C:\Python27" setup just like one would want.

Then, I decided to install WinPython, to get all the numeric and plotting packages it offered. This made a mess of things, as I could only use the extras packages, such as "numpy" and "scipy", from the "python.exe" installed at the Winpython folder.

This prompted me to reset all my environment variables to *that* python.exe, allowing me to use the packages I needed. I also took great use if IPython notebook, which came with WinPython.

Then, I took to downloading some different packages, such as py2exe, and also pip.exe, which installed themselves on the original "C:\Python27\Scripts" directory.

Now I've really made a mess of things, and I'm afraid of making this even bigger. I know this is a weird question, but I'm having more trouble with this than I'd care to admit.

**How do I salvage the libraries I already have and be happy using just one simple python.exe program, on one, simple, 'C:\Python27\' directory, without messing things up?**

Comment: You might find this useful: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: You may want to read this article http://www.aaronstannard.com/post/2012/08/17/How-to-Setup-a-Proper-Python-Environment-on-Windows.aspx

Answer (score 1):

WinPython is separate Python distribution - bundle of python and libraries. It won't play well with official Python distribution. You need to install libraries packaged for standard Python binaries. If you need SciPy stack, Windows installer can be downloaded from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ (search for Scipy-stack).